# htaccess clean urls with with sub folder

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm trying to create clean urls on my gallery website.

```
<http://sloanegalleryofart.com>
```

I was able to clean up general navigation. However, run in some hardcore difficulties while trying to configure sub folders

Curretnly my htaccess looks like so

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sloanegalleryofart.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.sloanegalleryofart.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/
RewriteRule (.*) /$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^about/$ /about/about.php
RewriteRule ^contact/$ /contact/contact.php
RewriteRule ^shows/$ /shows/shows.php
RewriteRule ^artists/$ /artists/artists.php 
RewriteRule ^books/$ /books/books.php
```

If I try to navigate from artists page `sloanegalleryofart.com/artists` to each individual artist it looks like so `sloanegalleryofart.com/artists/artist.php?artist=Gleb-Bogomolov`

When ideally I want it to be `sloanegalleryofart.com/artists/Gleb-Bogomolov/`. Just cut out the whole `artist.php?artist=` out of the url.

Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your solution

```
RewriteRule ^artists/([0-9a-zA-Z\-]{1,})?/?$ /artists/artists.php?artist=$1
```

When you access
`http://sloanegalleryofart.com/artists/Gleb-Bogomolov`
you will be seen
`http://sloanegalleryofart.com/artists/artists.php?artist=Gleb-Bogomolov`

Comment: Thank you so much !